# Play sound till dialogbox.dialogresult == dialogresult.OK

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog, messagebox

I am developing a winform application.
I want to play a sound file, till the dialogresult is OK for a message box. How can i achieve that.

For e.g.

```
 /*Till*/ (MessageBox.Show("Alarm") == DialogResult.OK)

 //Play a sound file
```

I tried while and do while but didn't succeed. Do i need to use background worker or run the code in a separate thread ??

Comment: How did `do while` not succeed? What happened instead?

Comment: @Code Gray: Yes true, but its client requirement. He wants to force himself to close the dialog box immediately as it appears. So he wants a continuous alarm.. !! I know its really annoying :)

Comment: I suppose a lot of message boxes popped up

Comment: @Niraj: Yeah, I deleted that comment after I read your *entire* question and realized you were creating an alarm. Annoying is OK for an alarm. ;-)

Comment: @Code Gray: It just dint go inside the loop. Message box was popped up but only once.I tried both conditions-- false and true but it dint work

Comment: Thats because the Message box show command is synchronous. The process waits until it finishes, which is when you click on OK.

Comment: @Christian: This gave me my answer. I must start a thread before messagebox opens; and as soon as DialogResult is OK i should stop the thread. Thannks again :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to roll your own threading. .NET class library already did it for you. This is how you can do it:

```
        SoundPlayer p = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\chimes.wav");
        p.PlayLooping();
        MessageBox.Show("Alarm");
        p.Stop();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, run the sound file in a seperate thread which you start when the messagebox pops up. Once the MessageBox comes back with OK you can make a call into that thread telling the music to stop, or you could kill the thread.

**EDIT**

An alternative would be to write your own AlarmMessageBox which inherits from MessageBox. Its only difference would be that upon creation it would start playing that sound and upon clicking ok it would stop. This could work in just one thread.

Comment: @Chirstian: Good idea to create a AlarmMessageBox. Will try it now. !

Comment: MessageBox has no constructors you can access, for all intents and purposes it acts as a static class, so that is not an option.

Comment: If you can start playing a sound upon creation and stop it when ok is clicked, then you don't need a separate class for this. it's like sound.start();MessageBox.Show("Alarm");sound.stop(). What is the benefit of the subclass?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen - That's a good point. One could create a custom MessageBox without inheriting from MessageBox. But that would be some work. So I'd suggest to just use two threads.

Comment: @Lasse: Yes, alarmMessageBox wont work. But threading is a good option. Thanks guys :)

Comment: @Zespri: Your idea is gr8. Let me check up.